# If an included picture is scaled and cropped, will the original size image be retrievable from the compiled *.pdf?

Tags: graphics

1. If an included picture is scaled and cropped, **will the original size image be retrievable from the compiled *.pdf** ?
2. ... and if so *how* ?
3. ... ... ... how to *prevent* ?

MWE-snippet:

```
\includegraphics[trim=0mm 0mm 0mm -5mm, clip, scale=0.15]{./figures/asdf}
```

Comment: The original image is included in the PDF file, as pdftex does nothing to it. What's the problem in being able to know the size of the image?

Comment: @egreg: The clipped content, which may contain confidential stuff. As I understand the OP, the original size is not the main concern, but the original size *image*.

Comment: @AlexG If the clipped part contains confidential stuff, the clipping must be done *before* including the image.

Comment: @egreg does the various software for cropping images etc. actually remove what is outside the crop boundaries?

Comment: @daleif That's to be verified with the specific software. I guess it also depends on the image format.

Comment: I ran convert ctan_lion1.jpg -crop 10x10+20+20 test_crop.png and the file size went from 81950 to 394.  I'm satisfied that the rest of the picture is gone.

Comment: The crop feature of Adobe Acrobat leaves the cropped part of the image intact in the file.  I unexpectedly found that out once, when including such an image in LaTeX produced the original uncropped image when printed out on certain older printers that were not up to date with their postscript drivers.  As a result of this experience, I do not rely on cropping software to do the job, but make sure my original crops the unwanted stuff directly.  Obviously, if you are willing to rasterize, you can crop stuff, but who wants to rasterize an image??

Comment: One explanation as to why cropped vector images still contain the original image can be visualized by the thought experiment of cropping a single letter. The letter is stored in the vector image as a single entity.  While you can crop part of the letter visually, the file does not create a whole new description of a cropped glyph.  It just stores the original glyph and a description of the crop box.  Because of this feature that vector elements take up finite space, which the crop box can arbitrarily bisect, it would be essentially impossible to throw away the cropped portion of a vector image

Comment: According to http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/crop-pdf-pages.html, "You can adjust the visible page area using the Crop tool and the Set Page Boxes dialog box. Cropping pages can help you create consistency within a PDF composed of pages of different sizes. Cropping does not reduce file size because information is merely hidden, not discarded."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: AFAIK Acrobat has also a destructive crop, which is what nutty wants. pdfTeX et.al. don't.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

As various comments already said: Included images (this goes for pdf and bitmap images) are always copied *completely* and *unchanged* into the output files; only the viewport is changed and/or scaled. No driver or engine does image manipulations.